# Abstract Class Difficulties: Inheritance From an Interface

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Forgive me, as Interfaces are still a new concept for me. I'm trying to create a simple re-themed "pong" styled game. I'm in the initial setup with it right now where I'm just creating the individual blocks on the screen that I will manipulate later in another class.

I wrote all the constructors, getMethods, setMethods, and Interface that I want to use with this class. However, when I try to compile and run the class and its runner, I get an error from my IDE that says "Block is not abstract and does not override abstract method getY() in Locatable".

*getY() is within the Interface Locatable*

I tried making this class abstract, and that solves the problem for this class. However, in my runner class, I cannot send the object from the runner to the original class, because now the class it is trying to send it to is abstract.

This is the beginning of the class I'm having issues with:

```
public class Block implements Locatable {
//instance variables
private int xPos;
private int yPos;

private int width;
private int height;

private Color color;

public Block()
{
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
}

public Block(int x, int y, int wdth, int ht)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    width = wdth;
    height = ht;
}

public Block(int x, int y, int wdth, int ht, Color col)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    width = wdth;
    height = ht;
    color = col;
}

public void setBlockPos(int x, int y)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}

public void setXPos(int x)
{
    xPos = x;
}

public void setYPos(int y)
{
    yPos = y;
}

public void setWidth(int wdth)
{
    width = wdth;
}

public void setHeight(int ht)
{
    height = ht;
}
public void draw(Graphics window)
{
  window.setColor(color);
  window.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public int getXPos()
{
   return xPos;
}

public int getYPos()
{
   return yPos;
}

public int getWidth()
{
   return width;
}

public int getHeight()
{
   return height;
}

public String toString()
{
   return "" + xPos + " " + yPos + " " + width + " " + height;
}

}
```

This is my interface that I'm trying to use in the class above:

```
public interface Locatable {

public void setPos( int x, int y);

public void setX( int x );

public void setY( int y );

public int getX();

public int getY();   }
```

And this is my runner class to test that this is working:

```
class BlockTestOne {
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Block one = new Block();
    out.println(one);

    Block two = new Block(50,50,30,30);
    out.println(two);

    Block three = new Block(350,350,15,15,Color.red);
    out.println(three);

    Block four = new Block(450,50,20,60, Color.green);
    out.println(four);
}   }
```

Is there anything else I need in the interface or in my 'Block' class?

Comment: your Block class has to implement the methods from the interface

Comment: @MartinS can you give me an example of the general syntax for implementing the interface? Still new at this whole interface thing.

Comment: `interface I { public void f(); }`
and then the implementing class has to implement the function
`class C implements I { @Overrides public void f() { ... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used "setYPos" in the class but "setY" in the interface. You have similar problems with your X and Y getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing the Locatable interface in Block class.
As per the contract, Block need to provide implementation for ALL the methods defined in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class can not be instantiated, so you either have to implement all the interface methods in Block, or create another class that extends from Block and implement the abstract methods, or implement the abstract method for Block inline, here is an example of the last option

```
Block one = new Block(){
    @override
    public int getY(){
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_abstraction.htm

Answer (score -1):

Let's see your code for class Block.

Comment: Just added the 'Block' code for you to take a look at